# Uso de Contains en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Hola amigos quiero hacer un insert, pero solo lo haré si uno de los parametros que esta recibiendo mi **SP**, en este caso la extención tiene la palabra **"pdf"**, entonces estoy tratando de hacer esto , pero me manda error :s

```js
Insert into ArchivosContratos
  (IdContrato, Nombre, Extension, Ruta, RutaWeb, IdUsuarioOperacion, fecha, Activo, esContrato)
values
  (@IdContrato, @Nombre, @Extension, @Ruta, @RutaWeb, @IdUsuarioOperacion, getdate(), 1, 1)
where contains(@Extension, '"pdf"')
```

Tambien traté con un if pero ... no me mandaba lo mismo

> if (contains(@Extension, '"pdf"')) ...

Gracias a todos por su ayuda y su tiempo.

Comment: probaste con `Like` ?

Comment: debería funcionar con tu if, pero, son necesarias las dobles comillas?   IF (CONTAINS(@Extension, 'pdf'))

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera buenas, lo que pasa es que no recibo la extencion como el puro texto, la resivo como  '.extension' por eso quiero usar contains y no like

Comment: Pero en ese caso deberías usar un `Like` de tipo `'%pdf%'`; esto verifica si es un varchar existe la palabra pdf, omitiendo si es al final o al principio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El **where** no se puede aplicar directamente a un **insert**, si deseas hacerlo es mendiante un **select** y ese **select** lo **insertas**, te dejo la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms174335(v=sql.90)). Lo que requieres para tu caso es una condicional, ya que lo que estas mandando es un **parámetro**.

Ejemplo **INSERT** con **SELECT**:

```
--INSERT...SELECT example
INSERT dbo.EmployeeSales
    SELECT 'SELECT', e.EmployeeID, c.LastName, sp.SalesYTD 
    FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
        INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
        ON e.EmployeeID = sp.SalesPersonID 
        INNER JOIN Person.Contact AS c
        ON e.ContactID = c.ContactID
    WHERE e.EmployeeID LIKE '2%'
    ORDER BY e.EmployeeID, c.LastName;
GO
```

Respuesta a tu caso:

```
IF @Extension LIKE '%pdf%'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ArchivosContratos (IdContrato, Nombre, Extension, Ruta, RutaWeb, IdUsuarioOperacion, fecha, Activo, esContrato)
    VALUES (@IdContrato, @Nombre, @Extension, @Ruta, @RutaWeb, @IdUsuarioOperacion, GETDATE(), 1, 1)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas usar el `WHERE` en tu `SP`, creo que lo que buscar es hacer algo similar a:

```
DECLARE @Extension AS NVARCHAR(255) = 'ejemplo de prueba.pdf';

IF @Extension LIKE '%pdf'
BEGIN
    -- Coloca aquí tu sentencia insert:
    INSERT INTO ArchivosContratos (IdContrato, Nombre, Extension, Ruta, RutaWeb, IdUsuarioOperacion, fecha, Activo, esContrato)
    VALUES (@IdContrato, @Nombre, @Extension, @Ruta, @RutaWeb, @IdUsuarioOperacion, GETDATE(), 1, 1)
END
```

Comment: persiste el error en el **where**

Comment: Que error es el que lanza?

Comment: En un insert no se puede hacer un where

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim puedes revisar la edición de mi respuesta. Si no te funciona o no es claro, te recomiendo agregar el procedimiento almacenado en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, lo que he realizado es declarar una variable de acción y utilizar el `IF` con `BEGIN` & `END`, fíjate en el ejemplo adjunto.

```
USE NAMEBD
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NombreSP]
    @cAccion            varchar(1)      = '',
    @nIdConcepto        int             = -1,
    @cNombre            varchar(100)    = ''

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @nError     INT
DECLARE @vchDescripcion VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @cNom VARCHAR(100)

ErrorProc:
    IF @nError <> 0 
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @vchDescripcion = description 
            FROM    master..sysmessages 
            WHERE   error = @nError

            SELECT -1                   Codigo,
                    @nError * -1        CodigoSql, 
                    @vchDescripcion     Descripcion
            RETURN -1
        END

    IF @cAccion = 'C' Or @cAccion = 'M' -- Creación o Modificación
        BEGIN

            if @cAccion = 'C'                               -- Inserta nuevo
                BEGIN
                    --INSERT INTO

                END
            else        
                BEGIN                                   -- Actualiza 
                    --UPDATE
                    SET @nError = @@Error
                END

        END

    ELSE                                        -- Solicitud de Eliminacion
        BEGIN
            --DELETE
        END
    IF @nError <> 0    
        GOTO ErrorProc
    ELSE
        SELECT  @nIdConcepto            Codigo,
                0                       CodigoSql, 
                'Ok'                    Descripcion

RETURN 0
```